# oracle not gathering histogram data for binary_double column

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production.

I want to gather histogram statistics on a table with a BINARY_DOUBLE column.

However oracle seems to be unable to do so correctly.

After I changed the column to the NUMBER data type it worked as expected.

To reproduce the issue I created the following script:

```
create table a(
  val binary_double not null
);

create table b(
  val number not null
);

BEGIN
    FOR i IN 0..49
    LOOP
       INSERT INTO a(val) (select dbms_random.value(10000, 50000) num from dual);
       INSERT INTO a(val) (select dbms_random.value(100000, 300000) num from dual);
       INSERT INTO b(val) (select dbms_random.value(10000, 50000) num from dual);
       INSERT INTO b(val) (select dbms_random.value(100000, 300000) num from dual);
    END LOOP;
END;

EXECUTE DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(OWNNAME => 'SYS', TABNAME => 'a', METHOD_OPT => 'FOR COLUMNS SIZE 4 val', estimate_percent =>  100);
EXECUTE DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(OWNNAME => 'SYS', TABNAME => 'b', METHOD_OPT => 'FOR COLUMNS SIZE 4 val', estimate_percent =>  100);
```

Checking DBA_HISTOGRAMS for table a

```
SELECT ENDPOINT_NUMBER, ENDPOINT_VALUE
FROM DBA_HISTOGRAMS 
WHERE OWNER = 'SYS' AND TABLE_NAME = 'A';
```

Result

```
ENDPOINT_NUMBER | ENDPOINT_VALUE

0   0
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   0
```

Checking DBA_HISTOGRAMS for table b

```
SELECT ENDPOINT_NUMBER, ENDPOINT_VALUE
FROM DBA_HISTOGRAMS 
WHERE OWNER = 'SYS' AND TABLE_NAME = 'B';
```

Result

```
ENDPOINT_NUMBER | ENDPOINT_VALUE

0   10976.7485097398
1   31489.048616045
2   49201.0216533027
3   200759.370719409
4   296991.623064998
```

Has someone an idea why this is happening and what to do about it? (preferably without changing the data type of the column)

Comment: Also seems to work for `binary_float`; and `width_bucket()` seems to work to, interestingly but unhelpfully. The behaviour is the same for me in 10.2.0.5 and 11.2.0.3, the only versions I have handy. (Not sure doing this as SYS is a good idea, but the effect is the same as a normal user).